# Download email attachments from outlook using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using following code to download outlook email attachments and images to folder. But it is throwing an error:
Cannot index into a null array.

Any guess why?

```
$o = New-Object -ComObject outlook.Application
$ns = $o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$f = $ns.Folders.Item(1)
$di = $f.Folders.item("Deleted Items")
$messagesWithAttachments = $di.items | Where-Object {$_.Attachments.Count -gt 0}
$messagesWithAttachments[0].Attachments.item(1).saveasfile("C:\test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided there are emails with attachments, give a filename instead of folder in the `saveasfile()` method.

Eg: `saveasfile("C:\test\test.txt")`